# Using Timer.schedule() with Milliseconds in Java

Tags: java, lambda, timer

I am trying to run a Timer to execute a lambda expression 1.8 seconds in the future.

```
private static Timer obRunTime = new Timer();

public static void main( String[] args )
{
    obRunTime.schedule(() -> {
    }, 1.8);
}
```

The problem here is .schedule can't take in a double. Is there a way I can cast it so the schedule will run for 1800 milliseconds or even a way I can take in 1.8 seconds?

Comment: `schedule` expects the number of milliseconds, so just pass 1800 instead of 1.8

Comment: I wasn't aware of this, had a hard time finding a good answer elsewhere. Thank you @Hugo!

Comment: You can always take a look at javadocs for issues like these: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule-java.util.TimerTask-long-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Timer obRunTime = new Timer();
        obRunTime.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("will be printed after 5 seconds");
        }
    },5000);
```

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware it expected the value in milliseconds!